# Understanding an observation about a theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a doubt on the following theorem.

Given a stochastic matrix M, $\mathbf{v_1},..,\mathbf{v_n}$ a basis of eigenvectors(possibly generalized) of M, with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1\,...,\lambda_n$ which satisfy $\lambda_1=1, |\lambda_j|<1, \forall j \ne 1$. Then we can choose $\mathbf{v_1}>0$, meaning that all the components of $\mathbf{v_1}$ are $\ge 0$ and there exists a strictly positive component. In particular $\mathbf{v_1}$ can be chosen to be a probability. Then my notes say that every probability $p_0$ may be written as $p_0=\sum_ic_i \mathbf{v_i}$, with $c_1=1$. They say that $c_1=1$ is natural, if one considers the fact that every $\mathbf{v_i},i\ne1$  is orthogonal to $(\frac{1}{n},...,\frac{1}{n})$, and that the latter is orthogonal to the n-dimensional probability simplex. Now, I thought a bit to this but I didn't understand why these last observations make the fact that $c_1=1$ more understandable. I have a proof of the statements above, so what I'm looking for is a more intuitive or geometrical explanation about why $c_1 =1$ is "natural", given that $\mathbf{v_i},i\ne1$  are orthogonal to $(\frac{1}{n},...,\frac{1}{n})$.